# the HTML script tag and non-JS content - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, scripting

It appears this code will request the file in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.

```
<script type="text/my-custom-mime-type" src="test.ashx">
</script>
```

Is there a some spec that says browsers should only process JavaScript related mime-types?
I know IE probably supports this because of the history with vbscript.

Once you have "content" like this downloaded how can you get access to it?
Does JavaScript/jQuery/? have some way of getting at this.

**UPDATE** 
So there is 2 parts to question. Sounds like for the first part - the browser will download what it will download and I guess there isn't much you can do about that based off the answers so far.

Example:
    `<script type="text/xml-script">`
      `<page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xml-script/2005">`
          `<components>`
            `<application load="page_load" />`
          `</components>`
      `</page>`
    `</script>`
    `</pre>`

this is a snippet from Microsoft's declarative MSAjax tech. Could you pull this in from an external file. Note: I'm not trying to use MSAjax here, but its a good example of a custom type being used for a script tag.

Part 2 - can you get access to the text if the "content" does download? For example, lets say its JavaScript - could you display it in a textbox? (without an explicit Ajax call)?

Comment: What code? Please post a proper example

Comment: I dont understand the question, can you give an example or elaborate?

Comment: If it is javascript why don't you declare it as such and if its not javascript what do you expect Firefox to do with it?

Comment: I expect Firefox to load the content, but then to do nothing with it if its unfamiliar with the mime-type.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm starting to see what you are trying to do. I'd have thought what you want to do is have your test.ashx return something readable as javascript (eg JSON). Are you ale to change what test.ashx outputs? Can you show us the kind of thing it outputs if it is fixed?

Comment: It can output any mime type. whatever it is it will be made up.

Comment: trying to put in Ruby, Python, <insert custom lang here> into the page. something other than JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a some spec that says browsers should only process JavaScript related mime-types?

See the [type attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-type-A):

> This attribute gives an advisory hint as to the content type of the content available at the link target address. It allows user agents to opt to use a fallback mechanism rather than fetch the content if they are advised that they will get content in a content type they do not support.

If you want to fetch arbitrary content for use in a script, use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question. Now I'm curious what the OP is trying to do...

Comment: Original Poster. Traditional term for the person who posted the first message to a thread on a mailing list, Usenet group or other forum.

Comment: Learn something new every day

Comment: @jtbandes This is very old, but I don't know what the confusion was. The OP is trying to load some client-side Atlas xml-script, and doesn't want the XML polluting the page (or perhaps wants it to have a different caching policy), so is trying to load it from an external source. (edit: I see, this was posted 20 minutes before an edit to the question. Explanation stands for anyone else who runs across this)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to specify script is

```
<script src="something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="somethingThatWilReturnJavaScriptMime.someextension" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There is no reason the browser should load unknown mime into a script tag and it will be strictly browser specific whether or not it will allow/ignore the type attribute

It would be a matter of testing to see what the browser will do if you actually send

***content-type:text/javascript***

regardless of type attribute

Comment: doesn't matter what content-type I send. I'm not trying to send text/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content type. Guessing .NET here so posting basic idea:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
         context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
         context.Response.Write("alert('hello world');");
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry was just using the ashx as an example. could be any file extension. this is just how I generate non-page content in .NET. But the script may even be a static file. Just wondering if its possible.